# Is having Lubuntu 12.04 a security risk?

Tags: 12.04, updates, lubuntu, security, lxde

I have a computer with Lubuntu 12.04 installed. Since unlike Ubuntu 12.04 Lubuntu is not LTS, I will not get Lubuntu updates.

However, I am still getting updates (I guess these are the general Ubuntu Updates).
Is having Lubuntu installed a security risk, or are the missing updates not security relevant?

Is it more secure to have Ubuntu installed and manually install the LXDE desktop? (The computer is a little bit to old for fluent use of the Unity desktop).

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**

I switched to 13.10 - still I am wondering what the answer to this question is.

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu 12.04 is an extra important version, because it's based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which will receive security updates until April, 2017.

For the software that's specific for Lubuntu (the LXDE desktop as such), Lubuntu 12.04 receives no more updates. But for the software that Lubuntu shares with Ubuntu, by far the most, Lubuntu 12.04 will receive security updates until April, 2017 as well. Things like Firefox, Adobe Flash Player, Libre Office and the kernel.

Normally I'm very much against running an operating system that doesn't receive updates anymore, but for Lubuntu 12.04 it's an acceptable small risk to keep using it until April, 2017. It's not likely that there will ever be a real threat from malicious software that targets outdated LXDE packages.